# Gcloud : Getting output from a template

Tags: gcloud

I have created a template to deploy a compute instance content of template is given below:

```
resources:
- name: {{ properties["name"] }}
  type: compute.v1.instance
  properties:
    zone: {{ properties["zone"] }}
    machineType: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/{{ properties["project"] }}/zones/{{ properties["zone"] }}/machineTypes/{{ properties["machinetype"] }}
    disks:
    - deviceName: boot
      type: PERSISTENT
      boot: true
      autoDelete: true
      initializeParams:
        sourceImage: {{ properties["sourceimage"] }}
    networkInterfaces:
    - network: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/{{ properties["project"] }}/global/networks/default
      accessConfigs:
      - name: External NAT
        type: ONE_TO_ONE_NAT
outputs:
- name: var1
  value: 'testing'
- name: var2
  value: 88
```

Deploying template using **gcloud** I am expecting the output in outputs field But, After Successful Deployment of template, I am getting outputs field blank as given below:

```
{
  "outputs": [],
  "resources": [
    {
      "finalProperties":.....
    }
}
```

Please suggest if I am missing out something.

Answer (score 0):

It looks weird/impossible to use `{{ properties["name"] }}` with `properties["name"]` as a variable.

I think you should create a parameter as it is shown [here](https://anil.io/blog/symfony/yaml/using-variables-in-yaml-files/)

Comment: I am using jinja template for deploying resources not yaml config files {{ properties["name"] }} works fine with template

Thanks I will look into it once "Creating Parameter in Yaml file"